# How can I get my wrapped column headings to horizontally align?

Tags: c#, centering, excel-interop

I'm creating a "column header row" on an Excel spreadsheet that ends up looking, in part, like this:

[image]

Note how the column headings that span multiple "lines" are not aligned horizontally within their cell. The last "line" seems well-centered, but those before/above it are off-center. e.g., with "Member Item Code", "Member" is *way* too far to the left, and "Item" is too far to the left also (but less so), while "Code" looks perfect. But my code is not really perfect, apparently.

I *am* applying horizontal alignment of "center" to these cells:

```
var unitHeaderCell = (Excel.Range)_xlSheet.Cells[rowToPopulate, DETAIL_UNIT_COL];
unitHeaderCell.Value2 = "Unit";

var custNumHeaderCell = (Excel.Range)_xlSheet.Cells[rowToPopulate, DETAIL_CUSTNUM_COL];
custNumHeaderCell.Value2 = String.Format("Customer{0}Number", Environment.NewLine);
custNumHeaderCell.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
custNumHeaderCell.WrapText = true;

var custNameHeaderCell = (Excel.Range)_xlSheet.Cells[rowToPopulate, DETAIL_CUSTNAME_COL];
custNameHeaderCell.Value2 = String.Format("Customer{0}Name", Environment.NewLine);
custNameHeaderCell.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
custNameHeaderCell.WrapText = true;

var memberItemCodeHeaderCell = (Excel.Range)_xlSheet.Cells[rowToPopulate, DETAIL_MEMBERITEMCODE_COL];
memberItemCodeHeaderCell.Value2 = String.Format("Member{0}Item{0}Code", Environment.NewLine);
memberItemCodeHeaderCell.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
memberItemCodeHeaderCell.WrapText = true;
memberItemCodeHeaderCell.ColumnWidth = DETAIL_MEMBERITEMCODE_COL_WIDTH;

var qtyHeaderCell = (Excel.Range)_xlSheet.Cells[rowToPopulate, DETAIL_QTY_COL];
qtyHeaderCell.Value2 = "Qty";

var bidPriceHeaderCell = (Excel.Range)_xlSheet.Cells[rowToPopulate, DETAIL_BIDPRICE_COL];
bidPriceHeaderCell.Value2 = "Bid Price";
```

What must I do to get *all* of these words to center (not just the last one)?

Comment: You don't need to add `Environment.NewLine` between words, you can use space between words and wrap the content of column, and based on column width, it will show in multiple lines.

Comment: But will it be centered? If not, that gives me no advantage. Actually, I'm testing it right now as we type...nope, didn't work - it doesn't wrap the text, even though I have WrapText set to true.

Comment: Yes it will be centered using both `tahoma` and `calibri` fonts. But when you use `Environment.NewLine` it only centeres using `calibri` and not `tahoma`

Comment: Yes, it's centered (and I am using Tahoma), but it doesn't wrap, and thus makes the column too wide.

Comment: I posted the code that I tested. Let me know the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add `Environment.NewLine` between words, you can simply use space between words and wrap the content of column, and based on column width, it will show in multiple lines.

In the below code, I set all cells in the range to wrap text and to be vertically and horizontally centered.

Also just for test I set the column width of 5th column.

```
//Using
using XL = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

//Code
XL.Application application = new XL.Application();
application.Visible = true;
var book = application.Workbooks.Add();
var sheet = book.Worksheets[1];

sheet.Cells[1, 1].Value2 = "Unit";
sheet.Cells[1, 2].Value2 = "Customer Number";
sheet.Cells[1, 3].Value2 = "Customer Name";
sheet.Cells[1, 4].Value2 = "Member Item Code";
sheet.Cells[1, 5].Value2 = "Qty";
sheet.Cells[1, 5].ColumnWidth = 30;
sheet.Cells[1, 6].Value2 = "Bad Price";

var range = sheet.Range("A1", "F1");
range.VerticalAlignment = XL.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
range.HorizontalAlignment = XL.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
range.WrapText = true;
```

And here is the result with default font settings:

[image]

And this is the result using customized font settings:

```
range.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
range.Font.Bold = true;
range.Font.Size = 9;
```

[image]

Comment: Nope, still no go; see Update 2.

Comment: How do you set the column width for that "Member Item Code" column?

Comment: It's set to 64. I'm not that yet, but sometimes I think about the Bea'les.

Comment: Can you wrap the text for that column using Excel?

Comment: What do you mean by, "Can you wrap the text for that column using Excel?" - uncomment the code where the cell value is normally wrapped?

Comment: Let the application open Excel and then try to wrap text using Excel environment. I want to see if there is a problem with that column or just the problem is its large width.

Comment: Also as another test, using the code, try to set the column width to 7 or 8 for example. 24 is too large.

Comment: Setting the col width to 8 worked. Now I'll have to do that for all the other cols, too, I reckon.

Comment: You can remove the updates from the question, to make the question more clean for future readers.